# How to buy and sell on the 15 minute time frame

Tags: btce, bots

Hallo I wanna write my first trading bot on python.
The bot should buy and sell on the 15 minutes time frame,
when the rsi is undersold or oversold.
How i can tell my bot to focus on the 15 minute timeframe ?

My code look like this

```
import talib as ta
date = []
price = []
volume = []
pair = eth_usd 

while True:
    tikcer = bteapi.getTicker(pair,conn)
    date =  ticker('server_time')
    price =  ticker('last')
    volume =  ticker('vol')
    price = np.array(price)

    if len(price) > 13
       EMAPrices = ta.EMA(price, 14)
       rsi = ta.RSI(EMAPrices, 55)
```